# How to do Ethash CPU mine using ethminer?

Tags: mining, ethminer, cpu

I have a Private Ethereum Network. I just want to do Ethash CPU mining using `ethminer`. I know that to have a smaller foot-print it is recommended to use GPU or openCL but for private networks, I only have few nodes on the network and all are CPU nodes. I just want my CPU node able to mine.

- For small private networks, I believe mining with CPU nodes, where all nodes are also CPU nodes in the network, will be no problem.

With the current model, if we have a `Parity` node there is no way for us to mine using a CPU node. And I am not sure why `Parity` forces users to mine with only GPU node. Since I do not have any GPU machine on my small private network, I am unable to use `Parity` node to do mining, it forces me to switch to `geth` node to do mining.

I have followed https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum .

**Install:**

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git
cd cpp-ethereum
```

**Build:**

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild
cmake --build build
```

After the build; `ethminer` used to exist under `build` folder on older versions git-tag:(`untagged-1d50efdb2f43825a1810`).

After I build, `ethminer` does not exist under `build`. So I was not able to find `ethminer` binary.

```
[$]~/cpp-ethereum/build$ ls
_3rdParty            deps     libdevcore     libethereum     libwhisper
CMakeCache.txt       eth      libdevcrypto   libevm          Makefile
CMakeFiles           ethkey   libethash      libp2p          rlp
cmake_install.cmake  ethvm    libethashseal  libweb3jsonrpc  test
CTestTestfile.cmake  include  libethcore     libwebthree     utils
```

---

So I have followed https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer to install `ethminer`.

This line to work for CPU mining: `./ethminer -F http://localhost:8545`

The error I am facing with the current/latest `ethminer`:

```
./ethminer
  ✘  11:20:06|ethminer  No OpenCL platforms found
```

**[Q]** Is there any way to prevent this error and force `ethminer` to mine on CPU platform? I guess we have find an older ethminer client that accepts `-C/CPU` flag.

I have also tried: `Genoil/cpp-ethereum` and it says.

```
./ethminer
CPU mining is no longer supported in this miner. Use -G (opencl) or -U (cuda) flag to select GPU platform.
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

---

Note: Two bounties did not return any answer. I opened an issue under github's ethereum-mining/ethminer hoping it will reach someone. You can follow from https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/issues/382.

Comment: cpp ethereum does not include ethminer, ethminer does. ethminer does not include cpu miner, they removed it. what does this question have to do with parity?

Comment: I am not able to mine with a parity node on a cpu machine. What should I do? Should I switch back to geth in order to mine. @5chdn

Comment: You get a +100 bounty if you rephrase your question to look for an Ethash CPU miner. I'm looking too.

Comment: Just did hope it is more clear, please feel free to fix my question if anything is missing or wrong. @5chdn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note the the github code I am sharing is [forked](https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/issues/5637) from https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum and **Version 1.3.0 of etherminer** that actually can do CPU mining, which is implemented around 1 year ago. I did some small changes to build the project, please see https://github.com/avatar-lavventura/ethminer.

First, since it will create new DAG do on the home directory: `rm -rf ~/.ethash`

**Dependencies:**

Linux-based:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libudev-dev cmake
```

macOS:

```bash
brew install leveldb libmicrohttpd
```

---

**Install:**

```bash
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/avatar-lavventura/ethminer.git 
cd ethminer
./scripts/install_deps.sh
```

**Build:**

```bash
cmake -H. -Bbuild
cd build/ethminer
make -j $(nproc)
```

---

```bash
$ pwd  # binary of etherminer is located under ~/ethminer/build/ethminer
~/ethminer/build/ethminer   
$ ./ethminer --version
ethminer version 1.3.0 | Build: ETH_BUILD_PLATFORM/ETH_BUILD_TYPE
```

**To Mine with your private Ethereum-chain:**

Please note that `geth` or `Parity` should work on the background as connected to your private ethereum network.

This line will use full horse power:

```bash
./ethminer -F http://localhost:8545
```

> -t, --mining-threads  Limit number of CPU/GPU miners to n (default: use everything available on selected platform)

```bash
[~/ethminer]$ cd build/ethminer
[~/ethminer/build/ethminer]$ ./ethminer -F http://localhost:8545 --mining-threads 2
```

---

Helpful comments:

- Build process here but with GCC 9.3.0, needed to insert the code patches as noted here in github (https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/issues/5637) , using `cmake -DTESTS=OFF`

Comment: Is there a version for Windows?

Comment: No unfortunately . @ulu

Comment: is there a way to connect it to the pool instead? if so which pool should be set up for this purpose. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am not sure, I think there is no pool on CPU mining

Comment: Thank you @alper , it works,I solved build issues downgrading g++. following this guide: https://achrafothman.net/site/how-to-downgrade-gcc-and-g-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I followed @alper's build process here but with GCC 9.3.0 I needed to insert the code patches as noted here in github: https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/issues/5637

I configured with `cmake -DTESTS=OFF`