# Can Parity and Geth work on a shared-blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I have a Private Ethereum Network. I cannot mine using `Parity`, if I have a CPU node. Issue: [How to do Ethash CPU mine using ethminer?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28062/how-to-do-ethash-cpu-mine-using-ethminer)

As a solution, I want to switch to `geth` node whenever I want to mine and switch back to `Parity` node if I do not need to mine.

In that case, I need to store the same blockchain for `Parity` and `Geth` processes, which is memory efficient.

Instead:

[Q] Can `Parity` and `Geth` work on a shared-blockchain?

For example, I can start my blockchain with `Parity` node, whenever I want to my I can switch back to `Geth` client and that will use the Parity's already created block chain. And when the mining completed I can switch back to `Parity` node again.

Please note that: I know that we can run `Parity` node and attach `geth` to use it as @Kannan Ravindran points in his answer. But when we do `geth attach` into an already running `Parity` node, we cannot execute `miner.start()` command, `Parity` does not allow us to do mining through `geth`.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Parity uses rockdb, and Geth uses leveldb instead. I'd say it is not an easy task to make both share the same blockchain storage. One option is to run two separate instances one for parity and one for geth and connect them, doing the mining in geth, and parity would sync to geth.

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand it correctly. You are trying to use a shared memory of the ethereum blockchain with 2 different node tools.

What you can try and do is, run a parity instance on `ipc` and `geth attach` to the parity via a custom `ipc` socket. The docs is given [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage#legacy-geth-console).

**Legacy Geth Console**

As of this writing, Parity's IPC socket can be readily attached to by Geth. To do this, run Parity with IPC enabled. You can then run Geth with the attach option, just like so:

```
$ geth attach ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc
```

It's no longer required to run Parity in --geth compatibility mode to use the Geth console.

Comment: Yes and no. I also want to run `geth` instance on Blockchain that is already generated by Parity. When I do `geth` attach into already running `Parity` node, I can not execute `miner.start(1)` command, `Parity` does not allow it. @Kannan Ravindran

Comment: oh, now that's a problem!