# How can I test mining ethereum using my MacBook Pro's CPU with a remote pool?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpu

This may seem like a stupid question, and maybe it is - I'm fairly new to all this.

My use-case is that a friend has deployed a pool and wants others to try it, just to test it for setup issues etc.

I don't have good enough hardware to try GPU mining, so have spent over a week trying to find a decent way to mine using the CPU on my MacBook Pro.

Lots of answers here just say 'Oh, if you want to test using CPU mining, just use Geth'. But they generally assume you're using it locally, with a private pool which is also running a Geth node on the same machine.

So, could I use Geth to test mining in my friend's pool? How do I set that up to point to his pool server?

And lastly, are there any better solutions? I've looked into the various forks of cpp-ethereum to see if I can get ethminer to work on my Mac, but so far all of the ones I've tried have dropped support for CPU mining altogether, which I find really weird.

Thanks all for any help you can provide.

Comment: This answer may help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28062/how-to-do-ethash-cpu-mine-using-ethminer

Comment: @Ismael - Yes, I eventually found that question and ended up using the suggested solution. Thanks anyway.